# How do I choose a directory name during zip on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, tar

Tar works fine:

```
tar -zcvf cli-layer.tar.gz cli_layer  --transform s/cli_layer/python/
ls -al
drwxr-xr-x 3 alexb alexb   4096 Dec 16 16:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 alexb alexb   4096 Dec 16 16:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 6 alexb alexb   4096 Dec 16 16:31 cli_layer
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexb alexb 150203 Dec 16 16:38 cli-layer.tar.gz
```

Uncompress creates new directory python instead of original cli_layer:

```
tar -xzvf cli-layer.tar.gz
ls -al
drwxr-xr-x 3 alexb alexb   4096 Dec 16 16:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 alexb alexb   4096 Dec 16 16:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 6 alexb alexb   4096 Dec 16 16:31 cli_layer
drwxr-xr-x 6 alexb alexb   4096 Dec 16 16:49 python
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexb alexb 150203 Dec 16 16:38 cli-layer.tar.gz
```

Is there any way to do it with zip?

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm afraid it is not implemented. You can give it a look in the [source code](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/) of `tar`. If I remember well there is a rather complex function in a separate file, named `transform.c`, of more than 600 lines. BTW welcome out on SuperUser.